# I want my mac to be able to leave afterimages of windows as I move them

Tags: macos, mac, software-recommendation

Per this image...

[image: But can you mac do this?]

I want my mac to be able to do this very fun activity. Is there a thing I can download that will leave afterimages on windows that I drag? Maybe if I hold a button first?

Comment: I would describe this as the ["bouncing cards from Windows Solitaire"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xYUxhx5Y3g) effect.

Comment: I want you to have this, too. Maybe someone can make a joke app that does it if the OS won’t allow such silliness